# How to get to router's settings site without connecting to this router's network?

Tags: networking, configuration, wifi, router

So... 
I want to connect to router's config site (eg. 192.168.1.1), but I don't want to connect with that router's network. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

To access a router from outside that router's network you have to turn on remote management in the router and then go in through the public IP and remote management port.

For example, in a newer Netgear you would click on Advanced and then Remote Management and tick the box that enables it.  Usually you can also set the port to use.  Say your IP is 123.123.123.123 and the router is set for remote management on port 8080.  You would put

```
 http://123.123.123.123:8080
```

in the browser and should then be prompted to log in.

Google the router's make and model with something like "enable remote management" and you should be able to find out how to turn on the remote management on your particular router.